# image onClick failing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onclick

I have a React component which renders an image. That image has to capture the onClick event, but it doesn't. There is no reason for this behavior. Here is the code:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

   imageClick = () => {
      console.log('Click!!!!');
   }       

   render () {
      return (
         <div>
            <img src='/myfolder/myimage.png' onClick={this.imageClick} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

I can't see why it doesn't shows me back the 'Click!!!!' message in the browsers console when click on the image. It gives me back no error, no warning, no nothing. I'm using Chrome 62.0.3202 running on Linux Mint.

When isolated this code it works, but within boilerplate it does not, which is my case.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What version of react are you using?
This seems to run just fine with 15.
[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/baVgpX)

Comment: Your code should work just fine, i don't see any issues with it, i would try to stop the bundle watch and rerun compile again

Comment: Yes, I'm using React 15.6. I've using React for a while and this is the first time it is truly overwhelming my mind.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say I'm using React boilerplate as well

Comment: @ShahafAntwarg I know it seems to be very simple, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: I've isolated the code and it works, but within boilerplate it doesn't

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {      
  
     render () {
        const imageClick = () => {
          console.log('Click');
        } 
        return (
           <div>
              <img src={require('/myfolder/myimage.png')} onClick={() => imageClick()} />
           </div>
        );
     }
  }
```

Comment: this is the same, in fact according to the React's official documentatio this is discouraged

Comment: Thanks you saved our life

Comment: I used `require('location').default` but when I log `e.target.src` I get "http://localhost:3000/static/media/Person-1.bb56f19f.png", but I need only 'Person-1.png'

Comment: How did this solve this issue? What's been done differently?

Answer (score 20):

I've been playing with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and noticed that logo had [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) css style set to `none` which disables all the clicks. Not sure if that is your case. Just try to override that style in your img:

```html
<img src='/myfolder/myimage.png' onClick={this.imageClick} style={{"pointer-events": "all"}} />
```

Comment: this is an old question which was solved long ago. Neverhteless I thank you for your time

Comment: Solved it for me! Wonder why they did that!

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved me a lot of time. I spent a happy hour trying to work out where my event was, but without your answer I am convinced I would not have figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

Well it does work in my case :

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  imageClick = () => {
    console.log('Click!!!!');
  }       

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src='http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/img_png/obj_64x64.png' onClick={this.imageClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

And the same version with a `prop` (url) passed to the component, as well as as `state` modification triggered when you click the image, as those two are important in React :

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicked : false
    }
  }

  imageClick = () => {
    console.log('Click!!!!');
    this.setState({
      clicked: true
    })
  }       

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={ this.props.url } onClick={this.imageClick} />
        {
          this.state.clicked &&
          <div>You clicked me!</div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent url="http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/img_png/obj_64x64.png" />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't work for me either, I thank you for your time

Comment: Well that's strange as both snippets indeed work. Hope you'll make it work in your environment ;-)

Comment: they indeed work, but when I put the code back into my project they stop working. I think there is something I'm using that is corrupting the normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine and here is the working sample with image `onClick`. I have tested on my machine `Chrome 16.0` working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React Image Click</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      class MyComponent extends React.Component {
          imageClick = () => {
            console.log('Click!!!!');
          }       

          render () {
            return (
               <div>
                  <img src='/myfolder/myimage.png' onClick={this.imageClick} />
               </div>
            );
          }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(
        <MyComponent />, 
        document.getElementById("app")
      );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is my same code. I thank you for your time, but it doesn't runs for me either. I really don't know what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageClick () {console.log('clicked');}
```

Just define the method as above and call the function like

`onClick={this.ImageClick.bind(this)}`

Hope it works

Comment: this is the same thing

Comment: Why is you rmethod capitalised?!?

Answer (score 0):

I have Found an alternative way to do that ....
I put image inside a button tag, and style that button to show nothing but image.
take a Look at my code :-)

```
 <button style={{background:'none', border:'none'}}>
   <img
     style={{cursor:'pointer'}}
     src={prova}
     type="submit"
     onclick={() => setTimeout(this.handleBtnClick(touched, errors),1)}
   />
 </button>
```